Question regarding range of logarithmic function
The question regarding which i am asking this question is as follows
Find the domain and range of the function
$$f(x) = \log_e(\sin x)$$
I found the domain easily as for the above function $\sin(x) \in (0, 1]$
However could not find the range of the function easily, i looked at the solution of the problem and it was as follows
Since, $0 < \sin(x) < 1$
$\therefore\hspace{2mm}-\infty < \log_e(\sin(x)) \leq 0$
Thus, the range is $(-\infty, 0]$
This solution i could not understand i could understand why $\log_e(1)$ is $0$ but how has $\log_e(0)$ been replaced by $-\infty$ is it some kind of assumption like $0! = 1$, could someone clarify this for me.

$\log(0)$ is not defined, but the image under $\log$ of the interval $(0,1]$ is the set $(-\infty,0]$, that is all numbers $\leq 0$.

You can fairly easily show that $\lim_{x \to 0+} \ln(x) = - \infty$. If you choose some (large, negative) $L<0$, then set $x=e^{L}$ which is really tiny.

What is your domain for $x$? I hope it prevents $\sin x\le0$. Cases with $\sin x<0$ can be handled in complex numbers, but require choosing a branch of the complex logarithm.

Think about the graph of $y=\log{x}$.
As $x \rightarrow 0^{+}$, $y \rightarrow -\infty$
$\log{0}$ is undefined

Nobody is claiming that $\log(0)=-\infty$ (please don't write $\log_e$). What happens is that the range of $\log$ restricted to $(0,1]$ is $(-\infty,0]$. So, if we are dealing with all numbers of the form $\sin(x)$ which belong to $(0,1]$, then the numbers of the form $\log\bigl(\sin(x)\bigr)$ (when $\sin(x)\in(0,1]$) are the numbers from $(-\infty,0]$.

Some people dislike $\ln$ and so write $\log_e$.  You may feel that $\log$ is better than either of those, but that does not make the others wrong.

@Henry Indeed. That's why I wrote “please” instead of trying to impose my will. Do you see something wrong in this?
